# C# FFMPEG: Code bugs out and stops producing media files

Tags: c#, cmd, ffmpeg

I've made a joke program in C# that uses ffmpeg to edit videos with different effects such as stuttering. I've finished 3 effects so far and each of them work on their own but as soon as I put one after another `e.g.  fx.CrashStutter(0, 2); fx.CrashBeep(2, 2); fx.Wow(4, 2);`
The code breaks and no longer produces photo/video files but once I stop debugging the file it was supposed to be processing appears. I've used a system where it loops over trying to execute a command to create a text file as a marker for when ffmpeg is done processing a file. The debug console also repeatedly says "The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe."

Here's the code for all 3 effects:

```
 public void Wow(double start, double duration)
        {
            if (fxstart == true)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("WowFX Duration" + duration);
                string folderName = ("W_s" + start);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("mkdir " + folderName);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd " + folderName);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -ss " + start + " -t " + (duration / 6) + " -i " + source + " a.mp4");
                //wait until a.mp4 appears
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\a.txt") == false)
                {
                    /*aha got a live one!*/FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo a > a.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -vf reverse -af areverse b.mp4");
                //wait until b.mp4 appears
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\b.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo b > b.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -ss " + start + " -t " + (duration / 3) + " -i " + source + " c.mp4");
                //wait until c.mp4 appears
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\c.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo c > c.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i c.mp4 -vf reverse -af areverse d.mp4");
                //wait until d.mp4 appears
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\d.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo d > d.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                string[] concatList = { "file 'a.mp4'", "file 'b.mp4'", "file 'c.mp4'", "file 'd.mp4'" };
                //FXcmd.StandardInput.Write("del a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt");
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\concatList.txt"), concatList);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -f concat -i concatList.txt -c copy " + folderName + ".mp4");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\" + "1.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo 1 > 1.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("copy " + folderName + ".mp4 ..");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + ".mp4") == false)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd ..");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cls");
                FXcmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            }
        }
        public void CrashStutter(int start, int duration)
        {
            if (fxstart == true)
            {
                string folderName = ("Cs_s" + start);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("mkdir " + folderName);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd " + folderName);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -ss " + start + " -t 0.1" + " -i " + source + " a.mp4");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\a.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo a > a.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -stream_loop "+10*duration+" -i a.mp4 "+folderName+".mp4");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\" + "1.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo 1 > 1.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("copy " + folderName + ".mp4 ..");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + ".mp4") == false)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd ..");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cls");
                FXcmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            }
        }
        public void CrashBeep(int start, int duration)
        {
            //this effect cannot last longer than 7 seconds
            double contrast = 25;
            double red = 0.75;
            if (fxstart == true)
            {
                string folderName = ("Cb_s" + start);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("mkdir " + folderName);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd " + folderName);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                /*gets stuck*/FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i "+source+ " -vf fps=1 a.jpg");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\a.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo a > a.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i a.jpg -vf eq=contrast="+contrast+" b.jpg");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\b.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo b > b.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i b.jpg -vf colorbalance=rm=" + red + " c.jpg");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\c.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo > c.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -loop 1 -i c.jpg -c:v libx264 -t "+ duration +" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1920:1080 d.mp4");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\d.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo d > d.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd ..");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("copy beep.mp3 "+folderName+"/beep.mp3");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd "+folderName);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i beep.mp3 -ss 0 -t " + duration + " e.mp3");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\e.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo e > e.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i d.mp4 -i e.mp3 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 " + folderName + ".mp4");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + "\\" + "1.txt") == false)
                {
                    FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(" echo 1 > 1.txt");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("copy " + folderName + ".mp4 ..");
                while (File.Exists("FxSource(Temporary)\\" + folderName + ".mp4") == false)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
                }
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd ..");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                FXcmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("cls");
                FXcmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I just turn it off and on again lol. I restart FXcmd after each effect.